# Site Usage Configurations in wss 3.0

Tags: sharepoint, wss

I have refered the following site to configure my search reports,

http://blogs.technet.com/b/praveenh/archive/2010/11/02/usage-reporting-in-sharepoint-wss-or-moss.aspx

but the problem is in `Activate Office SharePoint Usage Reporting` section

Following are the steps:

- On the Site Actions menu, click Site Settings.
- On the Site Settings page, in the Site Collection Administration section, click Site collection features.
- On the Site Collection Features page, click the Activate button for the Reporting feature.

But I Didnt see any `Reporting feature` in my `Site Collection Features page`.

Answer (score 0):

The `Reporting Services Add-in` was missing on my server.

I downloaded from here:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=9437

And now everything is working fine.